# How to get Total input files size in mapreduce driver class?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am looking to get the total input size in driver class.
I have multiple folders as input in HDFS.

Input path is like below.

/tmp/input/*/*/*/*/filename

It will take all files in all subfolders with filename.

I m looking to find total size of input in driver class.

Comment: You have to do some coding, i.e. recursively scan the directory and sum the file lengths. Use the File class.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But its That is not good way I guys. I m running more than 200 Jobs at time so adding recursion method will drastically increase my overall Completion time.

Comment: Well it's only really recursive if you have sub folders to process. Otherwise it's just a loop through a list of files to query the size of each for the sum, so if I am not mistaken it is O(n), even with sub folders it is fast as you make 1 pass through each querying the files.

Comment: can I use File class to access hdfs files? if yes can you please give me some sample. Thanks.

Comment: You really need to go read the documentation. A simple search would find you https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopandhive/home/hadoop-how-to-read-a-file-from-hdfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in a single call to the HDFS:

```
Path pattern = new Path("/tmp/input/*/*/*/*/filename")    
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
FileStatus[] statuses = fs.globStatus(pattern);
long total = 0;
for (FileStatus file : statuses) {
    total += file.getLen();
}
```

fs.globStatus(pattern) will list files in the same way as hadoop fs -ls

When you will initialise the inputs for the MR job, use the pattern and not the returned file statuses.